# How much do monsters get from Change Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, dragons

If you have a dragon or a couatl and have it change shape into, say, the CR 3 knight, what among brave, multiattack, leadership, and parry is "not a class feature" and would therefore be available to the creature?

And, does it get racial benefits on top of the knight's stats? In which case, if you have it turn to a variant human with the Tough feat, would you count its "level" as its CR or its number of hit dice? If that feat is just unavailable, then what if it turns into a mage that specifies it's an "x-level spellcaster"?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Please review the linked question and see if it matches yours; if not, feel free to edit your question to clarify what you're asking that's not already addressed.